# Фильтр на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Возможно ли на jQuery сделать подобный динмаический фильтр:

Есть список элементов с определенными классами. Элементы скрыты через атрибут css `display:none;`

В инпут юзер вводит слово и если оно равно классу элемента, то все элементы с таким классом отображаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Запросто](http://jsfiddle.net/KiTE/rttzt/):

```
​jQuery(function($){
    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        var value=$('#search').val().toLocaleLowerCase();
        $('#list li').each(function(){
            if( $(this).text().toLocaleLowerCase().search(value) != -1 ){
                $(this).show();
            }else{
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    })
})​;​
```

`#search` - селектор для поля ввода, а `#list li` селектор элементов списка

Comment: если оно равно **классу элемента**

Comment: Тогда так:

    jQuery(function($){
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            var value=$('#search').val().toLocaleLowerCase();
            $('#list li').each(function(){
                if( $(this).hasClass(value) ){
                    $(this).show();
                }else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        })
    });​